# Bad Request error only for selected parameters

Tags: spring-mvc

localhost:8080/TestProject/v1/segment/info?segmentNumber=5&memberType=N

this is causing "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"

while it is working fine for parameters 6 and N, issue with parameter pairs 5,N and 7,N

Please help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you send the request body?

Comment: thans for the response
i am using GET method
method signature as below     @RequestMapping(value="/segment/info", params={"segmentNumber", "memberType"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody Segment getSegmentInfo(@RequestParam(value = "segmentNumber") int segmentNumber,
   @RequestParam(value = "memberType") String memberType) {.........}    it is working fine for all parameter except 5,N and 7,N

Comment: Please, update your answer with the method. Don't  post it as a comment.

Comment: Can you copy your request parameters from your browser request. If you use chrome/firefox if you press F12, it will take you developer mode where you can find the request parameters and headers information. Can you send the request information.

Comment: Can you please edit your initial question and paste the code there. It is unreadable like this. Please include complete controller code.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem if you send the request like segmentNumber=5&memberType=N as per you controller code. Your controller declared as segmentNumber as int and memberType as string.

Receiving 400 Bad request when segmentNumber=N and memberType=5.

Can you make sure all time segmentNumber parameter carries an integer value?

Comment: thanks for response Premkumar, there was a Null record in DB for segmentNumber 5 and memberType N that was causing the issue.